# Make the compiler not optimize _ out

Tags: zig

I'm writing a benchmark of a simple function.

```
var timer = try std.time.Timer.start();
_ = f();
const elapsed = timer.read();
```

Unfortunately, the value marked with placeholder syntax gets optimized out, so `elapsed` equals zero. To fix this, i'm using a terrible hack:

```
comptime {
    asm (
        \\.global dummy;
        \\dummy:
        \\ret
    );
}
extern fn dummy(x: i32) void;

// ...
var timer = try std.time.Timer.start();
dummy(f());
const elapsed = timer.read();
/// ...
```

And it works as expected. I, however, am surely not happy with such a solution.
Similar code in Rust would just use `black_box` intrinsic, in Nim would use `used` pragma and in C it could be solved using `volatile` while declaring the result variable.

Is there a better solution in Zig?

Comment: `std.mem.doNotOptimizeAway`

Comment: @AliChraghi thanks, it worked! Could you please post this as an aswer so i could mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std.mem.doNotOptimizeAway`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:mem.doNotOptimizeAway):

```
std.mem.doNotOptimizeAway(f());
```

In the future, it will be replaced by [`@declareSideEffect`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/6168) builtin function:

```
_ = @declareSideEffect(f());
```